# "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" Issue with array logic

Tags: java, arrays, file, class, methods

Issue now is i'm getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

I've been fiddling around for a few hours and don't know if the problem is in `SalesManager` or `SalesAnaylzer`.

What I am trying to do is format the array values to money and and add lables Store 1.. and QTR 1... Im pretty sure I got the `totalSales`, `highestStoreSales`, and `averageStoreSales` correct 
Here is my code:

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.IOException;;

 public class SalesManager 
   {
  public static void main( String []args) throws IOException 
  {
    System.out.println(" What is the name of the file");
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName= scan.next();
    SalesAnaylzer sA = new SalesAnaylzer(fileName);
    /*System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println("Here are the stores' sales for the past four quarters:" +
                 "/n" + data);
    System.out.println("The total sales were:" + total);
    System.out.println("The highest quarterly sales were:" + highest);
    System.out.println("The average quarterly sales were:" + avg);*/
  }
 }
```

and here is this class file:

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;

 public class SalesAnaylzer 
 {

   DecimalFormat pricePattern= new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");
   int [][]sales= new int [3][4];

 public SalesAnaylzer(String fileName)throws IOException 
   { 

    File inputFile= new File(fileName);
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(inputFile);
    for (int row=0; row<4; row++){
      for (int col=0; col<6; col++){
        sales [row][col]= scan.nextInt();
      }
      }
 }
 public String toString()
 {
   String data = "";
   for (int row=0; row<4; row++){
     data =data +"\nStore "+(row+1)+": ";
   for (int col=0; col<6; col++){
     data =data + "QTR "+(col+1)+": "+pricePattern.format(sales[row][col])+" ";
      }
   }
 return data;
 }
 public double totalSales()
 {
   double total=0.0;
   for (int row=0; row<4; row++){
     for (int col=0; col<6; col++){
       total= total + sales[row][col];  
      }
   }
   return total;
 }
 public double highStoreSales(int store)
 {
   double highest=0.0;
   for (int row=0; row<4; row++){
     if(sales[row][store]> highest)
       highest =sales[row][store];
     }
   return highest;
 }
 public double averageStoreSales(int quarter)
 {
   double total=0.0;
   double avg=0.0;
   for (int col=0; col<6; col++){
     total=total+sales[quarter][col];
     }
   avg=(total/4);
   return avg;
 }
 }


java.io.FileNotFoundException: CompuDataSales (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at SalesManager.main(SalesManager.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at  edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: Try replacing the `fileName` variable with the actual file path and see if that works.

Comment: Well i'm needing the user to input the file name so fileName is never going to be the same

Comment: Does the fileName have spaces by any chance?

Comment: But where is the file supposed to be located? In a certain directory? Your code seems to be reading a file from the working directory, unless it contains a full path. You could use `new File(directory, filename)` and have a directory where you know the file is located.

Comment: yes the file is in the same directory

Comment: the file name the user is inputting is CompuDataSales   . I even tried  replacing it and having it just read the file without the user input and got the same result

Comment: Is `CompuDataSales` in the directory you run java from or in the directory the `SalesAnaylzer` file is in?

Comment: all of the files are in the same folder

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` and show if it prints the directory the file is in.

Comment: it does and its in the same location as the txt file

Comment: Depending on what system you're on, can you show output of [tag:ls] or [tag:dir] on that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using a filename with spaces inside of it. `scan.next()` takes the next "token" which is delimited by spaces. If your file name is for example: `C:\User\John Smith\Documents\file.ext`, then the `fileName` variable would only contain `C:\User\John`. Instead, use `scan.nextLine()` to grab everything up to the `Enter` key.

Unless you post your full stacktrace with it (every line of error output from the exception), we can't really see exactly what the issue is, so I'm going to make another guess at what the issue might be.

You may be using a filename without a full path and the program doesn't know where to find it.

- If you're using an IDE, the file should be in the same directory are your "src" and "classes" folders.
- If you're using the command-line, make sure that the file is in your "classpath". This is where the JVM looks for filenames that don't have full paths. This is often the same location as the `.class` or `.jar` file you're executing.

I can't think of anything else that could be wrong with your code, if nothing I mentioned fixes your issue, edit your main post to include the full stacktrace.

**Edit:** From the comment thread on this answer, we concluded that the issue the user was having was that they were excluding the file extension from the filename. `CompuDataSales` should have been `CompuDataSales.txt`. Other users having a similar issue should check to make sure that extensions are present in filenames.

Comment: file name is : CompuDataSales so theres no spaces in it

Comment: Does the file have an extension, like `.txt` or `.doc`? You're on windows, you should modify your folder options to show file extensions at all times.

Comment: yes its a .txt file  i even commmented out the user input and just called the file on its own and got the same result

Comment: The filename should be `CompuDataSales.txt`, not just `CompuDataSales`. The extension, though hidden on Windows by default, is still part of the full name of the file.

Comment: You said you've been putting in `CompuDataSales` but then said it was a `.txt`. It wasn't clear, sorry. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: i did that but it wouldnt work when i put it in myself but when I used  user input it finds the file

Comment: well its reading the file now when i put in CompuDataSales.txt but its returning "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:"

Comment: Your language isn't clear here. When the user types `CompuDataSales` it works? or when the user types `CompuDataSales.txt`?

What did you mean by "When I put it in myself"? In the code as `fileName = "CompuDataSales.txt";`?

We don't know what you mean unless you say it explicitly. Being vague doesn't help.

Comment: When the user types CompuDataSales.txt it works  but i now get the array out of bounds exception

Comment: Alright, so now your issue isn't reading the file, it's know your program's array logic. Please update the question's text so user's now the problem has matured to a different state.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47279/discussion-between-user2985542-and-axoren)

Comment: Well, now you have a different problem, but it should be clear if you look at your code's logic. `sales` is an array of size 3 by 4. You're accessing rows 0 to <4 and columns 0 to <6 in your for-loops.

The numbers starting from 0 going up to but excluding 4 are 0, 1, 2, and 3. And array with 3 indexes only has 0, 1, and 2. 3 would cause you to go outside the size of the array. You'll have a similar issue with 0 to <6. Study up on for-loops and how many times they iterate, how many spaces there are in an array, and what indexes work with the array.